# overriding ChangePasswordFOSUser1Controller prints code on login page

Tags: symfony, controller, overriding, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I'm curently developing an app on Symfony 2.5.0 using FOSUSerBundle, SonataAdminBundle and SonataUserBundle.
I've extended FOSUserbundle so my AppKernel.php has `new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle')` and I also generated my own Application\Sonata\UserBundle using Easy Extends.

In my Application\SonataUserBundle, i've overriden the ChangePasswordFOSUser1Controller as so:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Controller\ChangePasswordFOSUser1Controller as BaseController;

class ChangePasswordFOSUser1Controller extends BaseController
{
  public function changePasswordAction()
  {
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface)
      {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
      }
    $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.change_password.form');
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.change_password.form.handler');

    $process = $formHandler->process($user);
    if ($process)
      {
        $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'change_password.flash.success');

        if ($user->getFirstConnection())
          $user->setFirstConnection(false);
        return new RedirectResponse($this->getRedirectionUrl($user));
      }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('SonataUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
                                                               array('form' => $form->createView()));
  }

  /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   * {@inheritdoc}                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   */
  protected function getRedirectionUrl(UserInterface $user)
  {
    return $this->container->get('router')->generate('front_home');
  }

  /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   * @param string $action                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   * @param string $value                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   */
  protected function setFlash($action, $value)
  {
    $this->container->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set($action, $value);
  }
}
```

The problem is: Whenever I go to my login page I see my controller's code printed twice in the "header section", right before the login form.

I've tried clearing my cache and VOILA ! cache is cleared but the same code gets printed twice in my shell. (yeah, I work with a shell)

I get the "bug" over and over again when clearing cache but on my login page it disappears after two page refresh.

Have anyone tried overriding that controller or got a similar error ? (would be a shame no one had)

Thx for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
```

Missing on ChangePasswordFOSUser1Controller.php
The code was defined as interpretable and so printed as plain text on every html page.